# Unique constraint on two columns

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table called `QuestionMultipleChoice` that has the following structure:

```
ID int,
QID int,
Text varchar(200),
CorrectAnswer bit
```

I'm wanting to establish a unique constraint that consists of `QID` and `CorrectAnswer`. However, I only want to limit where `CorrectAnswer` is '1'.

```
CONSTRAINT QuestionMultipleChoice_UC UNIQUE (QuestionID, CorrectAnswer)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set `CorrectAnswer` to null instead of 0, then a unique index on `(QID,CorrectAnswer)` will only consider rows where `CorrectAnswer` is 1.

From the SQL-92 standard

> "A unique constraint is satisfied if and only if no two rows in a
>   table have the same non-null values in the unique columns. In
>   addition, if the unique constraint was defined with PRIMARY KEY, then
>   it requires that none of the values in the specified column or columns
>   be the null value."

Comment: Wouldn't I still have to create a `UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX`? Other sites seem to say that the unique constraint will still blow up with multiple null values.

Comment: @JustinAdkins as long as the index is unique, it shouldn't matter whether the index is nonclustered or clustered. give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a [Function Based Check Constraint](http://www.connectsql.com/2011/01/sql-server-function-based-check.html) or a [Trigger](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/an-introduction-to-triggers-part-i).

Something like this (I might have missed on the syntax):

A function that returns the number of correct answers for a question:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CheckAnswer(pQuestionId int)
RETURNS int
AS 
BEGIN
   DECLARE @retval int
   SELECT @retval = COUNT(*) FROM QuestionMultipleChoice c where c.QuestionId = pQuestionId and c.CorrectAnswer = 1
   RETURN @retval
END;
```

A constraint that uses the function to check whether this question has only one correct answer.
The check for `CorrectAnswer = 0` is for a slight optimization:

```
ALTER TABLE QuestionMultipleChoice
ADD CONSTRAINT chkAnswer CHECK (CorrectAnswer = 0 OR dbo.CheckAnswer(QuestionId) <= 1);
```